Hook civicrm_validateForm not being executed in Live Payment Page
I am finding an issue when validating a CiviCRM form, specifically a Payment Page, in Live mode, that it is not executing the hook/function civicrm_validateForm(), which has been implemented to add additional validations to the core CiviCRM validations.
Nevertheless, when I test the form in test-drive mode, the additional validations are executed.
I have seen the html page source of the Live Payment Page and the javascript function crmValidate() is there.
Any tip on why this is happening this would be much appreciated.

Which form you want to call the validateform on?

CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Main
